# Dudas con clave candidata ,clave primaria, clave alternativa

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, mysqli

Me asalta una duda tremenda con la siguiente cuestión ¿una clave candidata engloba a la clave primaria y a su vez si la hubiese a una clave alternativa?

Me explico, si tengo esto en una tabla:

(atributo1,atributo2,atributo3,atributo4,atributo5)

Si el atributo 1 y 2 son clave primaria y los atributos 3 y 4 son clave alternativa quiere decir esto que la clave candidata está formada tanto por la clave primaria como la alternativa?

Es que no tengo clara la relación entre clave candidata,primaria y alternativa en una relación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tanto la clave primaria como la alternativa , son claves candidatas. Pues una clave candidata es el conjunto de atributos que permiten diferenciar de forma única cada fila. Y en cuanto a la clave alternativa es aquella clave candidata que no ha sido seleccionada como clave primaria.

Espero te ayude, un saludo.

Comment: Coméntame si te sirvió de ayuda.

Comment: Ok, entonces en este caso los atributos 1,2,3, y 4 forman la clave candidata y ya dentro de esa clave candidata tenemos la primaria, atributo 1 y 2 y alternativa, atributos 3 y 4. Muchas gracias! Un saludo!

Comment: El tema es que una tabla puede tener varias claves candidatas, en este caso atributos 1 y 2 , formarían una clave candidata, y atributos 3 y 4 , formarían otra clave candidata. De esas dos claves candidatas , se elige la formada por 1 y 2 como primaria , y por lo tanto la formada por 3 y 4 pasa a ser la alternativa. Según entiendo yo.

Comment: El tema es que estoy con unos temas relacionales de base de datos y me piden que diga que dependencias debo crear entre los atributos para que NO sea Segunda forma normal (2FN)...Entonces yo entiendo que si atributo1 y 2 es primaria y atributo 3 y 4 es alternativa y el atributo 5 esta libre y depende de todas las claves candidatas esta en (2FN) .Entonces si yo creo una dependencia atributo1----->atributo 5 consigo que no sea (2FN) ya que el atributo 5 que no pertenece a ninguna clave candidata depende de un atributo de una clave candidata pero no de los dos que la conforman....Voy bien?